# Monitors connected to on-board HMDI and VGA ports shows blank after installing Nvidia Driver | Fedora 32

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, fedora, nvidia-graphics-card, kde-plasma-5

I am using a desktop with 3 monitors.

2 x 21-inch Dell monitors
1 x 34-inch LG monitor

The 2 Dell monitors, one is connected to the VGA port on-board, and the second one is connected to the onboard HDMI port.

The third and the large monitor 34 inches LG is connected to the HDMI port of NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 SUPER.

The system was using Windows 10, but I replaced it with Fedora 32 KDE last week, also installed Nvidia driver and CUDA successfully then. It has been working well until today, but I have no idea what really happened in the system or if some system update has undergone without my knowledge, when I tried to boot up the machine today morning, all I can see only the large 32inch LG monitor connected to Nvidia graphic card is showing up. The system is showing disconnected status for the rest two Dell monitors connected on-board VGA and HDMI ports which are using Intel onboard integrated GPU.

```
^ john @ fedora ~ > $ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 510 (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 [GeForce GTX 1650 SUPER] (rev a1)

^ john @ fedora ~ > $ sudo xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 2560x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 798mm x 334mm
   2560x1080     59.98*+  74.99    50.00  
   1920x1080     75.00    60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.93    59.94  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

^ john @ fedora ~ > $ sudo lsmod | grep 'i915\|nvidia\|nouveau'
i2c_nvidia_gpu         16384  0
nvidia_drm             57344  9
nvidia_modeset       1216512  24 nvidia_drm
nvidia              27701248  1286 nvidia_modeset
i915                 2621440  1
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        262144  2 nvidia_drm,i915
cec                    61440  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
drm                   626688  13 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
video                  53248  2 asus_wmi,i915

^ john @ fedora ~ > $ sudo nvidia-smi 
Mon Oct 12 18:14:56 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.28       Driver Version: 455.28       CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 165...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   49C    P8    12W / 100W |    465MiB /  3911MiB |      4%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1366      G   /usr/libexec/Xorg                 183MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1563      G   /usr/bin/kwin_x11                  86MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1566      G   /usr/bin/plasmashell               64MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1842      G   ...akonadi_archivemail_agent        2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1853      G   .../akonadi_mailfilter_agent        2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1860      G   ...n/akonadi_sendlater_agent        2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1862      G   ...nadi_unifiedmailbox_agent        2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2060      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files      113MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+


^ john @ fedora ~ > $ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

^ john @ fedora ~ > $ sudo grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX /etc/sysconfig/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=/dev/mapper/fedora_fedora-swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora_fedora/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora_fedora/swap rhgb quiet rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau modprobe.blacklist=nouveau nvidia-drm.modeset=1"

^ john @ fedora ~ > $ cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf 
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
options nvidia-drm modeset=1

^ john @ fedora ~ > $ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 455.28


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

nvidia-bug-report https://www.dropbox.com/s/tq3ozp5zsy426vr/nvidia-bug-report.log.gz?dl=0

nvidia-settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/501zE.jpg

What could be wrong here?.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue myself, check the following post for the solution:

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/monitors-connected-to-on-board-hmdi-and-vga-ports-shows-blank-after-installing-nvidia-driver-fedora-32/9655